# Eclipse Error: Unresolved Inclusion

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I know this question has been asked a lot but I have no idea what is wrong here.

I got some header files in `C:\svn\org.eclipse.tcf.agent\agent\tcf\framework` which contains all files that I need to compile an example program.

I inlcuded this path by opening the projects **Properties, C/C++ General, Paths and Symbols, Includes** and added the path there.

Eclipse doesn't find any of these header files.

[image]

Which results in:

[image: Eclipse doesn't find any of these header files]

The directory:

[image]

Can anybody help me here?

---

**Errorlog:**

```
10:23:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project org.eclipse.tcf.examples.daytime.agent ****
make all 
The system cannot find the path specified.
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -m, ...) failed.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [obj///Debug/tcf/main/main.o] Error 1
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'obj///Debug/tcf/main/main.o' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the paths in your `#include` statements. Clearly you should be adding `C:\svn\org.eclipse.fct.agent\agent` to your include path, not the sub-directories of that directory.